# Computing nth order derivative of $\frac{1}{(1-z)}$ using Cauchy's Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Let $f(z)= \frac{1}{(1-z)}$ be a complex function. The derivatives of this function are $f^n (z) = \frac{n!}{(1-z)^{n+1}}$. I can see that this is true by computing the first order, second order, and third order derivatives and noticing the pattern, but can we prove $f^n (z) = \frac{n!}{(1-z)^{n+1}}$ using the extension of Cauchy's Integral Formula? 
This question arises from example 4 on page 194 of Brown/Churchill's Complex Variables and Applications.

Comment: If the answer below was helpful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Sorry. I did not understand your proof. I hadn't reached the chapter on residue's yet. I have been reading about residues, and I still don't understand. I lose you when you say s=1. Isn't s the variable of integration over the closed curve C and z is some particular point inside the curve? I now have a different solution: look at the laurent expansion of 1/(1-z) and take the nth order derivative of that expansion. Thank you for your help. I appreciate your response. Math stack exchange is awesome, and I think its great that we have a community of people here that are always eager to help. :)

Comment: You are on the right track. I've revised my proof to address some details. See if that helped a bit.

Answer (score 1):

It's follows from the Cauchy Integral formula:

$$f^{(n)}(z)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{f(s)ds}{(s-z)^{n+1}}$$

Because what the formula means really, is that for any point $z=s_0$ enclosed by any closed countour $C$ we have:

$$f^{(n)}(z)|_{s_0}=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{f(s)ds}{(s_0-z)^{n+1}}$$

The Laurent series is exactly $\frac{1}{1-z}=f(z)$, so you have $s_0=1$ above and the residue is $R_{f}@(s_0=1)=1=numer(f)$, so the formula simplifies, precisely because the denominator now does not participate on the integration:

$$\begin{align}
f^{(n)}(z)&=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{f(s)ds}{(1-z)^{n+1}}\\
&=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\cdot\frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+1}}\cdot\int_C f(s)ds\\
&=\frac{n!}{2\pi i(1-z)^{n+1}}\cdot 2\pi i\cdot R_{f}@(s_0=1)\\
&=\frac{n!}{(1-z)^{n+1}}
\end{align}$$